# How to check if HTML5 FileSystemDirectoryHandle points to an existing directory

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

Lets say I am building an IDE and want to have an option to open recently used folders which also persists after a page refresh. References to FileSystemDirectoryHandle-s, obtained by `showDirectoryPicker()` are stored in an indexeddb, but real filesystem directory might have been deleted (at some point in time after referencing). What is the proper API to check if it points to an existing directory?

I was thinking of using `getDirectoryHandle` but I do not have parent reference, nor does it accept empty name argument.

I can try-catch `for await (const entry of directory.values())`, but this has some downsides (requires permissions granted, consider page refresh) and for that reason its not convinient ux to run through a list of handles (multiple confirms). I wonder if there is something more appropriate.

For the moment I am using

```
async getError(handle:FileSystemDirectoryHandle) {
    if(await handle.queryPermission({mode:"readwrite"}) !== 'granted'
        && await handle.requestPermission({mode:"readwrite"}) !== 'granted')
        return ERROR_NO_PERMISSION;

    try {
        for await (const _ of handle.values())
            return;
        return;
    } catch(error) {
        return error instanceof DOMException && error.code == DOMException.NOT_FOUND_ERR 
            ? ERROR_DOES_NOT_EXIST
            : ERROR_UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem but without some example of JavaScript ([mcve]), it's a waste of time trying to solve.  Just by what's posted ATM, I would suggest using good old fashioned flow control statements (`ifelse`).

Comment: `try/catch` is the right way: any other method is subject to TOCTOU bugs: a resource is not guaranteed to exist after a check.

Comment: `showDirectoryPicker().then(x => console.log(x))` -> `FileSystemDirectoryHandle {kind: 'directory', name: 'good cat videos'}`

Comment: I have reached for some more knowledge to https://github.com/WICG/file-system-access/issues/352